# Have any modern philosophers redone Descartes' Meditations?

Tags: epistemology, descartes, phenomenology, idealism, rationalism

With insights we get from the cognitive sciences, and advancement in philosophy in general (such as the coherentist theory of Truth) we would definitely do the Meditations differently.

Comment: I made a small edit which you may roll back or continue editing. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: You make a statement with no argument and I'd suggest changing it into a question. I'd say we'd definitely do it differently today, but not because of anything that's happened in the sciences or philosophy. We'd just learn from Descartes mistakes and the failure of his argument to win hearts and minds. . .  .

Comment: You can see E.Husserl, [Cartesian Meditations: An Introduction to Phenomenology (1929)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_Meditations).